# Scraping website with node.js request and getting weird characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nwjs

I used nwjs (ver 0.18.8) and I made a request on mangafox.me to do a mangareader.

It works with http://mangafox.me/directory/

When I try to make a request on a manga image like this one  http://mangafox.me/manga/onepunch_man/vTBD/c066/1.html I get these weird symbols:

> ��{s�F��[��w#Y�\�AI�(tY��dϯ���M%9���@�Cw��~���I(v��ں�ʑ�y���t��k2z������o��y���.^~wɌ�e���Ҳ�]?c�����Kf�=v��0�3? y`Y�_̘gY|fY���\�Q2����� �M���nV�iz�g���b$W�_a���c�C5

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind x) in fact it was just that the output was compressed in zip, so if you want to solve it if you have the same problem just add gzip: true in request header Ex:

```
request({url: '*****', gzip: true}, function(err, res, html){

   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

   //Do something

   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need node.js for something this simple. The easiest way to scrape a site is to load it into a hidden iframe and then just loop through the document's arrays of elements you need.

The document loaded gives you everything in arrays like these...

```
 Frame.contentWindow.document.forms

 Frame.contentWindow.document.scripts

 Frame.contentWindow.document.styleSheets

 Frame.contentWindow.document.embeds

 Frame.contentWindow.document.cookie

 Frame.contentWindow.document.images

 Frame.contentWindow.document.links
```

And so forth...